# CSS border cannot go to 0

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the border 0 in a table element. Using the Firefox Developer Console I set border:0 or border:none but nothing works. The computed parameter that firefox shows is this:

[image: border properties]

Clearly the property 0px should be applied but border is still 0.5px. Why is this not working? What else should I look into?

THis is the computed window shown in the image. I edited the property in the other window which is editable. This is shown because my edit was accepted showing `this.style > 0px` but the final `border-bottom-width` is still selected to be 0.5px

Comment: No one is going to be able to figure this out from a picture of a portion of your developer console.

Comment: It could help if you posted some code - relevant html & css

Comment: I was trying to create a test case with minimal HTML and CSS and in the process the problem got fixed. How that happenned is a mystery to me. Only thing I don't understand is why does the developer console show the information like that. It indicated the property applied is 0px but ends up with 0.5px. If it happens again in the future and I am able to replicate will update again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to edit in the wrong place, the window in your image is not for editing, see image below, I've marked where you can edit

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my post. I did edit at the spot you have shown that is why the computed list shows this.style > 0px. That is from my edit. And since it is the property that does not have a strikethrough I would expect the border-bottom-width to be 0px but somehow it is still 0.5px as the image shows.

Comment: I see, it is possible there is css for the bottom border somewhere else that overrides the border-bottom-width you are trying to edit, try to write "0px !important;" and see if there is a change, and if so, try to locate where the relevant css is

Comment: I tried important. It does not work. Also if something was overriding the property then this.style>0px whould have a strikethrough wouldn't it?